# call to method every time when button is clicked at each cell

Tags: iphone, ios

i have an customized cell that is loaded in table view cell and each cell have button with tag value. I need to call the IBAction method at each indexpath.row. For example if first row have that button than call should be made from first row to that action. Actualy i want to copy some text from each row when button is clicked and post it to Facebook.
here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell1";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
  if (cell == nil) 
  { 
      [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"audioviewcell" owner:self options:NULL];
      cell = nibloadedcell;
    }
fbbutton = (UIButton*) [cell viewWithTag:7]; 
  if(fbbutton)
  {
      [self facebookclick:(id)];
     }


  return cell;
}
-(IBAction)facebookclick:(id)sender
{

  }
```

i am unable to configure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this helps,

```
[cell.fbbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];   

-(IBAction)facebookclick:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *clicked = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    // do your things with your cell here.
    NSIndexPath *clickedPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:clicked];
    // do your things with your index path here.
}
```

Comment: giving error 'property fbbutton not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: where to write [cell.fbbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];   ?\

Comment: in your     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: is your fbbutton created in your custom cell?

Comment: shouldn't you use yourCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; instead of UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];?

Comment: but i have assigned my nibloaded cell to UITableViewCell. Please see the above written code.

Comment: @kai let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2479/discussion-between-ketan-rajput-and-kai)

Answer (score 0):

The method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will only return a cell. Try calling your action in the UITableViewDelegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` instead. This is what's called when a cell is selected.

Comment: i know that i have to do work upon 'didselectrowatindexpath', but bunch of code shoal i implement?

Answer (score 0):

```
 [cell.fbbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlTouchUpInside];

  -(IBAction)facebookclick:(id)sender
        {
          button1 = (UIButton *)sender;
          // By this u got ur whole cell here...
         UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[button superview];
         int row = [tblView indexPathForCell:cell].row;

        }
```

You can also assign button`s tag and get content of particular row of your array...

By

```
button1 = (UIButton *)sender;
 int row = button1.tag;
```

Hope This is useful to you...

Comment: giving error "interface typecast cannot be statically allocated"